# Delayed socket.io response, and "warn - websocket connection invalid"

Tags: node.js, socket.io, httpd.conf

I am running a nodeJS + Express + socket.io + httpd application on an AWS EC2 instance.

Upon loading the page, the logger provides this information:

```
GET / 200 2ms - 1.23kb
GET /javascripts/script.js 304 1ms
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1ms
GET /images/052.png 304 1ms
GET /Candara.ttf 304 1ms
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
   warn  - websocket connection invalid
   info  - transport end (undefined)
   debug - set close timeout for client EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
   debug - cleared close timeout for client EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
```

At this point, things will halt for about 5 seconds, after which:

```
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP?t=1376937523124
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 1::
   debug - set close timeout for client EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP?t=1376937523490
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client EgWLPeyO2uiCTSui01CP
```

After this point, things start working well as far as I can tell, and events are fired and received without delays (if an event is fired *before* the 5 seconds delay described above, they will not be processed until after the delay has completed). The problem is how to remove that 5 seconds delay.

The client-side JS looks like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var socket = io.connect("http://xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", {resource: "/socket.io"});
```

The server-side JS looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require("socket.io").listen(app.listen(3000));
```

My httpd.conf file looks like this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    allow from all
</Location>
```

How can I avoid the initial delay and establish a healthy connection to socket.io?

Comment: The problem is likely in your proxy.  Does the version you are running have full support for websockets?

Comment: I am just running Apache/2.2.25. Do you mean there is something that I need to do in regard to Apache?

Comment: Likely - yes.  Support for websockets may or may not be in that version (I'm not sure), or you many just need to adjust the configuration.  From the description of your problem, it sounds like socket.io is falling back to long polling.  If you haven't done so already, put socket.io in verbose debug mode - it'll tell you what protocol(s) it's attempting.

Comment: I have now added a full description of what goes on in the logger (only the first half of the question has been edited).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the problem by restricting the allowed transport methods to "xhr-polling" and "jsonp-polling". I believe this is because Apache/2.2.25 doesn't offer support for the others.

The relevant code was added server-side:

```
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling", "jsonp-polling"]);
```

Comment: I was just commenting when I saw this being posted :).  This will work, but then you lose the benefits of websockets.  You'll also want to make sure that, if/when you start running multiple servers either your load balancer is configured for sticky sessions or that you persist your sessions (redis.io or other) so requests can be made on any server.